# Can not get access to Telescope dashboard

Tags: laravel, laravel-telescope

I want to add telescope into my laravel 8 app, but having in .env

```
APP_ENV=local
TELESCOPE_ENABLED=true
```

and reading at site :

```
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope
The Telescope dashboard may be accessed at the /telescope route. By default, you will only be able to access this dashboard in the local environment.
```

on url

```
http://local-tads.com/telescope
```

I got 404 error, where http://local-tads.com - is local hosting of my app

In app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php file I added lines :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
...
        if ($this->app->environment('local')) {

            $this->app->register(\Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider::class);


            \Event::listen(
                [
                    TransactionBeginning::class,
                ],
                function ($event) {
                   ...
```

I have unmodified vendor/laravel/telescope/config/telescope.php file.
Have I to add route in  routes/web.php and in which way ?

How to get access to telescope dashboard ?

**UPDATED BLOCK :**
I run both commands :

```
php artisan telescope:install

php artisan migrate
```

But I did not find config/telescope.php, so I copied it from /vendor/ subdirectory

Running command

```
php artisan route:list
```

has no any “telescope” entry.

In file app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php I added lines with  telescope :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Library\Services\AdminCategoryCrud;
//use App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\TransactionBeginning;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\TransactionCommitted;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\TransactionRolledBack;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

use Laravel\Telescope\IncomingEntry;
use Laravel\Telescope\Telescope;
use Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
            $this->app->register(\Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
            $this->app->register(TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
        }
```

Not sure if all is correct?
in env I have :

```
APP_ENV=local
TELESCOPE_ENABLED=true
```

and in composer.json I added line :

```
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/telescope"
            ]
        }
    },
```

and updated composer

But http://local-tads.com/telescope - still raise 404 error...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pls look at UPDATED BLOCK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this problem but I attention Laravel Documentation I watch this code and run them:

```
telescope:install
```

**, you should remove the**

> TelescopeServiceProvider

service provider registration from your application's

> config/app.php

configuration file. Instead, manually register Telescope's service providers in the

> register

method of your

> App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

class.

Answer (score 2):

A potential answer to your problem could be removing the telescope package from the `dont-discover` array. So your new `extra` section would be like this one:

```json
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to dump your autoload by running `composer dump-autoload` in your project folder. I hope this helps you :D

For more information please check [this issue on the github repository](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/954).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked to clear the route cache of the Laravel application.

```
php artisan route:clear
```